# Firebase PHP-API installation

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

To verify users for firebase I want to use https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-php which depends on https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt
But how to install?
I've checked out both resources in 'libs/firebase-token-generator-php' respectively 'libs/php-jwt'

The problem:
"firebase-token-generator-php" uses `include_once 'JWT.php';` and that's neither in the same folder nor in my include path.

It would really be easier if I could use composer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your composer.json as in this example:

```
{
    "name": "example/firechat",
    "type": "project",
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "composer/installers": "v1.0.12",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "*",
    "firebase/token-generator": "*"
}
```

}

Include the libs in your installation, eg:

```
include_once ABSPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Use the libs in your code, eg:

```
$tokenGen = new \Services_FirebaseTokenGenerator( "#great-token-from-firebase-app-manager#" );
$token    = $tokenGen->createToken( array( "uid" => 'custom:1'), array( "admin" => true ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are PEAR packages, so you can download tgz files and install them by PEAR. This way they will be added into your include path.

Other way you have, is to add `libs/php-jwt` to your include path manually (in ini file or using [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php))

Comment: Yes I know, but PEAR isn't helpful for me (Cloud based hosting without full server control). I've added the include path, but I think it's not the best method.

Comment: You can always fork these repos and add composer.json, remove unnecessary `include_once` and include forks in your `composer.json`.